# Thumbnails from not explorer "native" files (like windows does for jpg, png etc)

Tags: c#, windows, thumbnails

What I want to do is force Windows to use my program as a base for creating thumbnail from some kind of files that are not images.

In Windows you can see thumbnails from images, word documents, pdf´s etc - this is what I want with other file types. I can create bitmaps from these files (which later I want to use as a thumbnails) and store them somewhere.

My question is how to connect extension with request of creating/checking if they exists thumbnail with my program and returning image/path to image. Any help and example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a COM DLL library, with a class that implements [`IExtractImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761848%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You then register your *shell extension* with the file **extension** you support under:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[.ext]\shellex\[SID_IExtractImage]
@default = [MyExtractImageShellExtensionCLSID]
```

Where

- `.ext` is the extension of file you are creating a viewer for (e.g. `.psd`)
- `SID_IExtractImage` is the constant `{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}`
- `MyExtractImageShellExtensionCLSID` is the class id (`clsid`) of your shell extension that implements `IExtractImage`

So, if i were registering a Photoshop `psd` extension handler, and my COM object's clsid is `{CCB7DB3B-D073-4606-B246-2A5174D274C8}`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.psd\shellex\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}
@default = {CCB7DB3B-D073-4606-B246-2A5174D274C8}
```

Then it's just a matter of creating a COM object that implements:

- `IPersist`
- `IPersistFile`
- `IPersistStream` (optional)
- `IExtractImage`

And Explorer will use your extension to create a thumbnail of a photoshop image.

**Note**: If you're running 64-bit Windows you will need a 64-bit compiler, to create a 64-bit COM object DLL, that 64-bit Windows Explorer can load.

Comment: Thanks for this,  could you explain where to place the  compiled dll?

Comment: @Sturm Since your dll is doing to be a *"COM library"*, it will use the standard COM registration mechanism. I'm sure it's explained somewhere in MSDN. But i have [an answer here that explains a lot of it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/285060/12597). It starts with the important point that you have a `clsid` (e.g. `{CCB7DB3B-D073-4606-B246-2A5174D274C8}`), and optionally you can have a `ProgID` (e.g. **Acme.SuperPdfImageExtractor**)